# De-referencing char pointer run-time error

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

Why does the below code cause a run-time crash?

The code itself is not very useful, but , by creating a pointer to a char pointer and pointing to string literals in main, passing this pointer to my function and trying to read the strings causes problems. Why is that exactly?

By creating an array of strings instead in main however (commented out) , there are no problems in passing and reading the strings. Thanks in advance for your knowledge.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* GetString(char** strs, int strsSize);

char* GetString(char** strs, int strsSize)
{
    return *strs;
}

int main()
{

    char** stringArr = {"ab", "abc", "abcd"};
    //char* stringArr [] = {"ab", "abc", "abcd"};

    char* resultStr;
    resultStr = GetString(stringArr, 3);

    printf("%s\n", resultStr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A pointer is not an array; an array is not a pointer.

Comment: Why compiler did you use that did not provide a warning about `char** stringArr = {"ab", "abc", "abcd"};`?

Comment: mingw. See them now. Why shouldn't it be a compiler error rather than warnings?

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pendantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )  warning: unused paramater: `strsSize` can be fixed by inserting the statement  `(void)strsSize;`.  and the declaration of the `strArray` is not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initializer for `stringArr` is not valid.  You have a pointer to a pointer, not an array.  A pointer cannot be initialized with the `{}` syntax.

When compiling with `-Wall -Wextra`, the following warnings are produced:

```
/tmp/x1.c: In function ‘main’:
/tmp/x1.c:15: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/tmp/x1.c:15: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
/tmp/x1.c:15: warning: (near initialization for ‘stringArr’)
/tmp/x1.c:15: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
/tmp/x1.c:15: warning: (near initialization for ‘stringArr’)
```

The commented out declaration you have is the correct one.

Both declarations are valid to be passed to `GetString` because an array decays into a pointer to the first element when passed to a function.  However, a pointer and an array are not the same thing.